# potential advantages/disadvantages of window.location over a tag with href?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I inherited some code with `<img src="../...gif" onclick="aURL">`.

I was wondering the reason behind this choice so I would like to know **any potential advantages/disadvantages of window.location over a tag with href**?

I am considering changing to `<a href="aURL"><img src="../...gif"></a>`.

Thanks,

Comment: Without JavaScript I'm assuming the inherited page/code doesn't work? I'd view that as a profound disadvantage, personally.

Comment: ha, i did come across the cgi.http_referer not being available but then realized that variable could be altered anyway by a user.

Answer (score 4):

The main disadvantage with the `<img onclick="">` approach I immediately see is that various forms of clicks will not work, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click opening in a new tab, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click opening in a new window, etc.

Also, JavaScript being disabled is also an area the `onclick="window.location=x;"` fails.

Definitely use an anchor here like you're thinking, that's its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As for the reason, I can't speak to that.

Typically, you're always better off setting the href on an anchor, even if you don't intend to use it. The href should be set as a fallback in case the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, or if a bot is crawling your site and won't use the onclick event. If you have to open a popup, then put that in the onclick and return false so it doesn't hit the href. I would definitely recommend removing the onclick from the `<img>` and putting it in an `<a>` wrapping it.